# Need help with SQL Server query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I want write this query in SQL Server

```
from (
    select DISTINCT salary 
    from employee 
    order by salary desc
) 
where rownum = 3;
```

Comment: So.. what is your question?  Are gremlins stopping you from writing the query?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [ROW_NUMBER()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx):

E.g.,

```
WITH EmployeeSalary AS
(
    select salary, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by salary desc) AS 'RowNumber'
    FROM employee 
    group by salary --you can't use DISTINCT because ROW_NUMBER() makes each row distinct
) 
SELECT * 
FROM EmployeeSalary 
WHERE RowNumber = 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT salary 
FROM employee 
WHERE rownum = 3 
ORDER BY salary
```

The caps are optional. Is rownum a column in employee or are you looking for only the third row returned?

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Thanks EvoD , rownum is not column. I m lokking for 3rd row